# Django 2.2 How to send a static input value to Database

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a ModelForm and i have created a Button with a value in html, but i cant send this value to my mssql database. It should send the value on a click on the button, but it does nothing.
I want to submit the number 200 to the database in the field 'Bunkernumber'

my form:

```
class BunkerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bunker
        fields = '__all__' (fields are: ID,Bunkernumber, Bunkername)
```

my view:

```
def Bunker_view(request):
    updatebunk = BunkerForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        updatebunk = BunkerForm(request.POST)
        if updatebunk.is_valid():
            updatebunk.save()

    context = {'updatebunk': updatebunk}
    return render(request, "pages/bunker.html", context)
```

my html:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="card text-center text-white  mb-3" id="bunker1">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Bunker 1</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                         <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " name="bunker2000" 
                                                                                            value="2000">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
  </form>
```

what can i do to save the value "2000" to my database?

Comment: ``name="bunker2000" ` != "Bunkername"` template fields are mapped to form class fields by `name` attribute. So fix the name in the template.

Comment: <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " name="bunker2000"                                                                                           value="2000"> 

you mean i have to rename name="bunker2000" to name="bunkernumber" ?

Comment: Right, Bunkernumber.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Hi Ivan, do you know a solution for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125585/django-sql-server-hot-to-bind-checkbox-values-to-a-specific-id-in-database ?